# Установка Less на windows 8.1

Tags: css, less

Искал информацию в сети но не нашёл её , как установить less ?Если можно подробнее

Comment: Нагло врете - https://www.google.com/search?q=less+%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D0%B2+windows&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: ну а установить точно так же, как на вин7 не прокатывает?

Comment: вам нужен less или компилятор ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

less не устанавливается ни на виндовс ни на linux ни на какие либо другие системы less подключается к html страницам к примеру вот структура

```
img
css
script
less
index.html
```

где img,css,script,less это папки
то less.js засовываем в папку script создаем фаил style.less и в index.html прописываем следуещее

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="less\styles.less" />
```

и

```
<script src="script\less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

причем первая запись должна быть выше второй а из компиляторов попробуйте winLess